# Change an object's properties at run time?

Tags: python, properties, wxpython, runtime, wxwidgets

I have a project in Python 2.7 and wxPython. I have both IDLE and Boa Constructor available as IDEs.

I need to change one or more properties of a GUI object, such as a button, at run time - especially size, location, and text (the latter in buttons and labels).

How do I change these properties at run time? Mind you, I'll be using absolute position with most GUI objects.

Comment: What have you tried so far? wx is pretty good about providing a `SetLabel()` method for objects with a Label, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, as I need to make sure this is possible BEFORE I spend too much more time rebuilding my application in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JasonMc92, Yes it is definitely possible to change a wx object's properties (labels, size, position, etc.) on demand within your application. What you need to do is read up on wxPython event handling to know how to catch actions like clicking a button and add your instructions to change your desired properties as required.

You can download the wxPython demo from their [download section](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) which includes working examples for the majority of the controls wxPython has to offer. You can also view wxPython's Online documentation [here](http://www.wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php), and New documentation [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/). You can also check out [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/) for more technical information regarding wxPython event handling. I can also recall that Boa Contructor has it's own methods for defining events within it's interface. I would suggest checking the provided help and documentation for Boa for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the widget's label or value are simple things. You can probably change a widgets location if you are using absolute positioning, but I think that would be counter-intuitive for the user. I know I wouldn't want my Close button to change locations all the time. I think you can set the size using its SetSize() method, but that might require a refresh. It would take you about 10-15 minutes to actually try this yourself.